# Ranking column per frequency

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I would like to rank a dataframe according the a frequency count that I have already in my dataframe. Basically if the count is higher then 1 then just to give a ranking on a scale, 1 being the lowest frequency and highest number of the scale represents the highest frequency count. An additional column that has the ranking of these:

Example DF R:

```
df <- data.frame(gene_cluster = c("Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene3", "Gene4", "Gene5","Gene6"), GCF= c(1343,1343,1321,1312,1321,1343),
                     GCF_Frequency = 3,3,2,1,2,3)
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want to order by the _values_ of the `GCF Frequency` column or by the _frequencies_ of these values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you wan the rank function:

```
df$GCF_Rank <- rank(df$GCF_Frequency,ties.method="min")

  gene_cluster  GCF GCF_Frequency GCF_Rank
1        Gene1 1343             3        4
2        Gene2 1343             3        4
3        Gene3 1321             2        2
4        Gene4 1312             1        1
5        Gene5 1321             2        2
6        Gene6 1343             3        4
```

There are multiple ways to handle ties based on your preference. `“average”, “first”, “random”, “max”, “min”`

Comment: This is pretty cool! I was wondering if it would be possible to do it with various qualities actually, like if I had more columns in my df, I could include this into the ranking system.

Comment: You can accomplish almost anything with programming. If my answer addressed what you have asked for then consider marking it as accepted. If you have additional questions consider asking them separately or editing your current question. Make sure to include a desired output to help make your questions more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure if that's what you want, but if you want to order by the *values* of the `GCF Frequency` column (given that these already are your computed frequencies), this is easily achieved with the `arrange` function from the `dyplr` package:

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(gene_cluster = c("Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene3", "Gene4", "Gene5","Gene6"),
                 GCF= c(1343,1343,1321,1312,1321,1343),
                 GCF_Frequency = c(3,3,2,1,2,3))

df <- df %>% 
  arrange(GCF_Frequency)

print(df)
  gene_cluster  GCF GCF_Frequency
1        Gene1 1343             3
2        Gene2 1343             3
3        Gene3 1321             2
4        Gene4 1312             1
5        Gene5 1321             2
6        Gene6 1343             3
```

If you want to sort the variable in descending order instead, just wrap it in `desc`, as in:

```r
df1 <- df %>% 
  arrange(desc(GCF_Frequency))
```

Comment: I want to create an additional column that ranks these according to their frequency count as mentioned, like if they have just one GCF then they will be a certain rank etc